# R: ks.test ECDF gives different results

Tags: r, statistics

Do you know why I get different results between

`ks.test(a, b)`

and

`ks.test(ECDF(a), b)`?

I assumed ECDF didn't change the distribution

Comment: Where is the `ECDF` function defined?

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/CoSMoS/versions/1.0.1/topics/ECDF

Comment: I'm very surprised that your code even runs without error. `ECDF` returns a data.table of probabilities and values. That's obviously not the same as a vector of values. Testing seems to indicate that `ks.test` unlists the data.table, though at a quick glance at the source code I can't understand why that happens.